# WinDbg Problem with ntoskrnl

Tags: windows, windows-vista, 64-bit, windbg

I've got a similar problem to "[BSOD - Unable to verify timestamp for ntoskrnl.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/33320/bsod-unable-to-verify-timestamp-for-ntoskrnl-exe)", in that I can't seem to get the correct symbols to read `ntoskrnl`.

I've followed the [advice given by BK1E](https://superuser.com/questions/33320/bsod-unable-to-verify-timestamp-for-ntoskrnl-exe/33337#33337), but still can't get a result.

Text from debug below:

```
Loading Dump File [C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\WER9D78.tmp\Mini030610-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\Windows\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ntoskrnl.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ntoskrnl.exe
Windows Server 2008/Windows Vista Kernel Version 6002 (Service Pack 2) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`01e59000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0201ddd0
Debug session time: Sat Mar  6 14:08:20.516 2010 (UTC + 0:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:42:01.723
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ntoskrnl.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ntoskrnl.exe
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.........................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck A, {11, c, 0, fffff80001ec9489}

***** Kernel symbols are WRONG. Please fix symbols to do analysis.
```

How do I fix this issue?

OS is Windows Vista x64 SP2.

Comment: After running ".symfix", could you try running ".reload /f"?

Comment: oh gawd, not the bugchecks... ptsd... acting up again.... _*twitch*_

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're loading a minidump, which requires a path to the executable.  Either set the _NT_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE_PATH env var to point to your %windir%\system32 folder (or whatever holds your executables), or use the `.exepath` command in windbg.